# Django Simple History - Tracking M2M field changes (with "through")

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-simple-history

I am using django-simple-history to track changes to my fields, and from what I see, it seems like django-simple-history does not track changes to M2M fields. I tried introducing an intermediate model for the M2M fields, and then attaching a HistoricalRecords() field within that intermediate model, but it seems like there is no use for that, unless I am using the django-simple-history wrongly. It seems like whenever I add a new relation in the M2M field (with "through"), a new instance is created within the intermediate model referencing foreign key relations to the two models with M2M relations, and whenever a relation is removed, that corresponding instance in the intermediate model would be deleted. If that is the case, how can I track the changes of the M2M fields through the intermediate model? Since the instance would be deleted whenever it is removed as a relation, which would lead to the tracking to not exist, since that instance no longer exists. I am new to django-simple-history, so do guide me along if I missed out or misunderstood anything, thanks all!

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class CustomerInformation(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

class SalesProject(models.Model):
    sales_project_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sales_project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customer_information = models.ManyToManyField('CustomerInformation', through='Project_Customer')
    history = HistoricalRecords()

class Project_Customer(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('SalesProject', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('CustomerInformation', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

serializers.py

```
class ProjectCustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectCustomer
        fields = ('id')

class SalesProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer_information = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=CustomerInformation.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = SalesProject
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        customers = validated_data.pop('customer_information')
        project = SalesProject.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for customer in customers:
            project.customer_information.add(customer)
        return project

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        customers = validated_data.pop('customer_information')
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        instance.customer_information.clear()
        for customer in customers:
            instance.customer_information.add(customer)
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class SalesProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     serializer_class = SalesProjectSerializer
     queryset = SalesProject.objects.all()
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? I am not too sure how I am supposed to handle the intermediate model's creation and update of relations together with the base model (SalesProject), so I handled it manually in the create and update methods of the ModelSerializer of SalesProject, so that when I create and update a SalesProject instance, I am able to update and create the M2M relations within the intermediate model (ProjectCustomer), all in 1 call. I am not sure if the way I did is correct, especially the update method, as I am clearing all the existing relations to add new ones, so maybe that is where the issue arises from, but I am not sure what the correct way to handle this is, so do guide me along!

All help is appreciated, thanks all!

Comment: Unfortunately the django-simple-history did not implement m2m fields up to this date. The discussion on main repository is here https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history/issues/399 . To have m2m tracked you would need to update the code yourself. It shouldn't be complicated.